Magnetically resistive material?
I'm working on an electromagnet and I'm trying to get the magnetic field further out, not necessarily stronger, just in a different place. I'm wondering if there's some sort of material that exists that will actively "resist" magnetic flux, as in, would force the magnetic field to go around it.

In a word, it's no

Superconductors exclude the magnetic field from their interior (beyond a thin layer near the surface maybe 100nm deep), but that’s probably not very useful for you.

Short answer: no (assuming normal test conditions at the earth's surface for temperature, air pressure, gravity, magnetic & electric fields, etc.)
Longer answer: Have you considered the converse of this, ie: a material that enhances rather than resists the magnetic field, thereby encouraging the field to go where you want it, rather than discouraging it from the places you don't want it?  This is commonly done, there are many materials that increase the B field for a given H  above what occurs in free space (air), by factors ranging from 10s to 1000s of times.
Magnetics is very application-specific, apart from the magnetic field strength parameters you are trying to achieve, you must carefully specify many other factors, such as:-

Physical dimensions & constraints.
Means of excitation (how the H is generated): amplitude, frequency, waveshape.
Available power to drive the means of excitation.
Operating environment: temperature, humidity, air pressure, vibration, etc.
Application: is this device being used to sense some change in a physical quantity, or transmit information, or transmit power, or create a field to lift a magnetic material against gravity?

